# How to use ffmpeg and pipe the result to a stream with spawn in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, spawn

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./a.h264');
const command = spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', 'pipe:0', '-c', 'copy', '-o', 'pipe:1']);
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./a.temp.h264');
readStream.pipe(command.stdin);
command.stdout.pipe(writeStream);
```

I want to pipe stream to ffmpeg and output to another stream,How can I use ffmpeg and pipe the result to a stream with spawn in nodejs?

Answer (score 3):

To read the docs from nodejs I know if there is just one stream input, just do like this:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./a.h264');
const command = spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', 'pipe:0', '-c', 'copy', 'pipe:1'],{
  stdio: ['pipe','pipe','ignore']
});
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./b.h264');
readStream.pipe(command.stdin);
command.stdout.pipe(writeStream);
```